# How can I save the value of a String that is ParseInt()ed into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, exception

Basically, I need to use the `Integer.parseInt()` function to convert 10 strings into integers which will then be averaged.

Also need to catch any Exceptions but I'm confused as to how to keep the program running so that when the user makes an error the array stays in the x value before the mistake was entered and keeps asking for a correct integer.

Running this right now gives an error since intNum can't be made into a variable, I'm sure it has to do with how i arranged my do and try methods?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    int p=1;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tenNums[] = new int [10];
        
    for (int x=0; x<10; x++) {
            
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        String stringNum = scan.next();
        do {
            try {
                int intNum = Integer.parseInt(stringNum);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            }
            p = 2;
        } while (p == 1);
        tenNums[x] = intNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare the variable `intNum` outside the `do`-`while` loop and just assign it in that scope. Otherwise, you won't be able to access it outside the loop, a variable declared there can only be accessed there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `p == 1` as a condition for invalid output, you can just `break` of inner loop when an entered number is valid:

```
    for (int x=0; x<10; x++) {
        int intNum = -1;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter number: ");
            String stringNum = scan.next();
            try {
                intNum = Integer.parseInt(stringNum);
                break;
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            }
        } while (true);
        tenNums[x] = intNum;
    }
```